# How does anonymous functions work in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, anonymous-function

How does anonymous function know what parameters are being passed in? For example,

Case 1:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Case 2:

```
$( "li" ).each(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Case 3:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index, element ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + element + $( this ).text() );
});
```

In each of these cases, how does the anonymous function know what `e`, `index`, `element` are?

Comment: Because `.each` passes those values to the function. Also note that your second example doesn't work, because `.each` doesn't pass an event object to the callback. And you can name the parameters however you want to.

Comment: In all of your cases, the first element will always be the same thing. index = e. In javascript, you don't have to specify the number of parameters you send to a function. You just have to make the function adapt to that number of parameters and each new param will be some precised thing. Then, `.each` passes the values you specify to the anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

Because [the code in `each`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.each) will call the function you pass it with the arguments.

```
function notEach(callback) {
    callback(1,2,3);
}

notEach(function (one, two, three) {
    console.log(one, two three);
});
```

Comment: yes, but why can't you use index.preventDefault() for example? Sorry I am a noob and I don't get this.

Comment: @guest: You are confusing `.each` with one of the event handling methods, such as `.click`. See https://api.jquery.com/each/ and https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @guest — Because it doesn't pass an event object in (which makes sense, because each is used to run some code on each item in an array, not to set up an event handler).

Comment: well let's forget about each. I don't care what function I use. I am solely talking about the anonymous function that is inside each.

Comment: @guest: Uh? So what's your question now if it's not about `.each`?

Comment: @guest — We can't forget about `each`. The arguments a callback function gets called with depend entirely on the thing that is calling it. When you pass a function to `on` it gets called with an event object (which has a `preventDefault` method) because you passed it to `on`, not because it was an anonymous function.

Comment: @guest: If it helps, have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L290). As you can see in `callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );`, the callback gets passed the index as first argument and the element itself as second argument. That's also described in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/): *" Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0."*. And what Quentin said, whether the function is anonymous or not has nothing to do with that. `$( "li" ).each(foobar)` would work exactly the same.

Comment: OK I understand what you are saying now. It basically depends on the handler and object being passed to each method, such as `each`

Comment: @guest: Yes. You are passing a callback to the methods (e.g. to `.each` or `.on`) and then that methods calls it in *some* way. Usually the documentation explains which values are passed to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

If we can speak of `each` as if it's a little robot, `each` tells the function what its arguments are. It picks up the collection and the function, puts the elements of the collection into the function one at a time, and sticks the outputs together as a collection. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

You should understand that when you write an anonymous function, it's both a procedure and an object. You are simultaneously defining for Javascript how to carry out that function ("knowing how" to call it) and what that function is ("knowing that" it is a particular object). Some languages are still in use where a function is not an object. So maybe that fact was confusing when you encountered it here.

Answer (score 0):

[naive implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/V2NbX/1/) of `each` function:

```
function $(selector) {

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    return {
        each: function (fn) {
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                fn(i, elements[i]);
            }        
        }
    };
}
```

The jQuery function returns an object with an `each` function. This function has access to the matched elements and iterates over them. It can call the function you gave it on every iteration and pass the current index and corresponding element to it.

Your second case doesn't make much sense to me. [As far as I know jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), no event is passed to the `each` function.